# Change the title of the page according to the title of a division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a specified element is visible to viewport, the title of the page will change because of the element is visible to viewport, but how can I change the title according to the 'title' of a division

[This is the jsFiddle, Feel free copy paste it to try it tho](https://jsfiddle.net/astroXoom/v72hg25z/1/)

[Live Viewing/Testing for Results](http://prospekt.ml/stackoverflow/bugs/scrollTitleJS/)

(Some of the codes are from the GitHub repo "jQuery.isOnScreen"; I don't claim the right to say it that it is mine, but i'm trying to use it and modify it for my website, kudos to the original dev :D)

By the way, here is the javaScript code:

```
// This Gets the Article Title from a Division!

$.fn.is_on_screen = function(){
    var win = $(window);
    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};

if( $('.target').length > 0 ) { // if target element exists in DOM
    if( $('.target').is_on_screen() ) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
      document.title = "An Article"; // show this if visible
    } else {
        document.title = "Prospekt | A Gaming Community"; // show this if NOT visible
    }
}
$(window).scroll(function(){ // bind window scroll event
    if( $('.target').length > 0 ) { // if target element exists in DOM
        if( $('.target').is_on_screen() ) { // show this if it's visible to dom
            document.title = 'It is Magic! | Stackoverflow'; // show this if visible
        } else {
        document.title = "Prospekt | A Gaming Community"; // show this if not visible
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I got is to replace this code

```
if( $('.target').length > 0 ) { // if target element exists in DOM
if( $('.target').is_on_screen() ) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
  document.title = "An Article"; // show this if visible
} else {
    document.title = "Prospekt | A Gaming Community"; // show this if NOT visible
}} 
$(window).scroll(function(){ // bind window scroll event
if( $('.target').length > 0 ) { // if target element exists in DOM
    if( $('.target').is_on_screen() ) { // show this if it's visible to dom
        document.title = 'It is Magic! | Stackoverflow'; // show this if visible
    } else {
    document.title = "Prospekt | A Gaming Community"; // show this if not visible
    }
}
});
```

With this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ // bind window scroll event
        if( $('.target').length > 0 ) { // if target element exists in DOM
if( $('.target').is_on_screen() ) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
  document.title =  $('.target')[0].title; // changes the document title to the target title.
}}});
```

**EDIT**
In order to make this work with more targets use this code instead.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() { // binds window scroll event
 $.each($('.target'), function(index, value) { //for each element in the target class
     theTarget = value //sets the variable theTarget to the value of the current index of the target class     
         if ($(theTarget).is_on_screen() && theTarget) { // if theTarget element is visible on screen after DOM loaded and(&&) theTarget exists
             document.title = theTarget.title; // changes the document title to the theTarget's title
         }
 });
 });
```

**EDIT**
In order to set a default title use this code. Edit the 'defaultTitle' variable to set a default title, otherwise it auto detects the title. If your targets are two far apart, it will result in the title changing from Article 2 -> Defualt -> Article 3.
Code:

```
var defaultTitle = document.title; //automatically gets original title from the title element and stores it in a variable. you can also just set a title here as the default.
$(window).scroll(function() { // binds window scroll event
    if (!$('.target').is_on_screen()) {//if all of the targets are not on screen.
        document.title = defaultTitle; //set the title to the default
    }
    $.each($('.target'), function(index, value) { //for each element in the target class
        theTarget = value; //sets the variable theTarget to the value of the current index of the target class
        if ($(theTarget).is_on_screen() && theTarget) { // if theTarget element is visible on screen after DOM loaded and(&&) theTarget exists
            document.title = theTarget.title; // changes the document title to the theTarget's title
        }
    });
});//only triggers on scroll, you may want to also put it in $(document).ready()
```

Comment: Now it is working, Thank you very much! but here's another problem, if I have 3 more "targets", how can I make it work, because the javaScript is only detecting the 1st target and not the other targets tho :(

Comment: Hello? Are you still active?

Comment: Okay, I'll get to it.

Comment: I finished, and it should now work. The code is in the edited answer.

Comment: This is the last question, how can I make the title go back to default if the element isn't available in the element area? btw thanks for the effort :) You're a good programmer inside and outside, keep up the good work!

Comment: I answered your last question. Thanks. If anything else doesn't work leave another comment here, and I can help you out.  I hope you can accomplish your project done. :)

Comment: Thank you for your support :) I can't finish it without you :) Have a Good Day sir!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is determine if your element is visible in the viewport.  The code you have already does this, so I didn't bother tweaking it.

Next, you need to get a title.  Rather than having all of this extra JS around, I thought it might be best if you put the title in the markup.  Ideally, your page will be in sections that will already have headings, and you can just get the text from there.

```
<section>
  <h1>This is a heading for this section</h1>
  <p>Some content goes here.</p>
</section>
```

Perhaps in other cases, you don't want the title to be chosen by the heading.  For those times, we can just as well get it from a data attribute.

```
<section data-page-title="Section with data attribute title">
  <p>
    This section has no heading, but its title comes from a data attribute!
  </p>
</section>
```

We can handle both cases with simple code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $sectionEl;
    $('section').each(function (index, sectionEl) {
        $sectionEl = $(sectionEl);
        if ($sectionEl.isOnScreen()) {
            document.title = 'Title Prefix | ' + (
            $sectionEl.data('pageTitle') ||
            $sectionEl.find('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').text().trim()
          );
          return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/mnzLkdc8/1/  Note that the title of the page cannot be changed in the fiddle itself, but you can use `console.log()` to see the data.

I also recommend [debouncing](http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation) the scroll event so that there isn't a lot of overhead as scrolling is happening.